# Adding images to R object

Tags: android-resources, android-image

I'm having a problem calling images that are sitting inside the res folder, and I assume I'm doing something wrong.
I've read several posts in SOF stating that all i need to do is to add all the images in a flat way to the res folder:
[image]

But I can't reach them in the code below (the code in under MapsActivity)

```
private BitmapDescriptor
    getMarkerIcon(Job.jobTypes jobType){
        switch ((jobType)) {
            case LIFESTYLE:
                return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(android.R.drawable.lifestyle); <-- states it cannot find the resource
            case DELIVERY:
                break;
            case PRIVATELESSONS:
                break;
            case HANDYMAN:
                break;
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a way of returning to another function the current image for the map marker based on the enum type.

Answer (score 0):

Resource files cannot have space in their name. Remove spaces from the file names.

Load image from your resource:

```
  return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.lifestyle);
```